# Qt layout content is not visible

Tags: c++, qt, qlayout

In this project a  QVBoxLayout's content is invisible, I tried every single things but nothing changed. The layout's name is topLeftLayout. BottomLeftLayout and right layout are  correctly visibles on the screen. I've no idea.
This is the code:

.cpp

```
#include "math.h"

Math::Math(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(0)
{
    mainWidget = new QWidget();

    titleLabel = new QLabel(mainWidget);
    titleLabel->setText("Math Helper v. 0.0.0");

    bottomLabel = new QLabel(mainWidget);
    bottomLabel->setText("Made with C++ and Qt Framework");

    aboutQtButton = new QPushButton(mainWidget);
    aboutQtButton->setText("About Qt");
    
    quitButton = new QPushButton(mainWidget);
    quitButton->setText("Quit");

    // ????
    topLeftLayout = new QVBoxLayout(mainWidget);
    topLeftLayout->addWidget(titleLabel);
    topLeftLayout->addWidget(bottomLabel);
    topLeftLayout->addStretch();

    bottomLeftLayout = new QHBoxLayout(mainWidget);
    bottomLeftLayout->addWidget(aboutQtButton);
    bottomLeftLayout->addWidget(quitButton);
    bottomLeftLayout->addStretch();

    leftLayout = new QVBoxLayout(mainWidget);
    leftLayout->addLayout(topLeftLayout);
    leftLayout->addLayout(bottomLeftLayout);

    rightLayout = new QVBoxLayout(mainWidget);

    mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout(mainWidget);
    mainLayout->addLayout(leftLayout);
    mainLayout->addLayout(rightLayout);

    setLayout(mainLayout);
    setWindowTitle("Math Helper");
    setFixedSize(windowWidth, windowHeigth);
}
```

Comment: You should use arguments more carefully (and read the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#QLayout)), including in constructors: `layout = new QLayout(parent);` is the same as `layout = new QLayout;` followed by `parent->setLayout(layout);`. Only your first `new QVBoxLayout(mainWidget);` is actually applied, all the following attempts are ignored, including `setLayout(mainLayout);`. You can use [layouts in Designer](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html) to make tests and know how they are eventually created by viewing the code preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign several layouts to your widget. From the documentation `QLayout::QLayout(QWidget *parent): The layout is set directly as the top-level layout for parent. There can be only one top-level layout for a widget.`

Untested:

```
#include "math.h"

Math::Math(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    //mainWidget = new QWidget();

    titleLabel = new QLabel;
    titleLabel->setText("Math Helper v. 0.0.0");

    bottomLabel = new QLabel;
    bottomLabel->setText("Made with C++ and Qt Framework");

    aboutQtButton = new QPushButton;
    aboutQtButton->setText("About Qt");
    
    quitButton = new QPushButton;
    quitButton->setText("Quit");

    // ????
    topLeftLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    topLeftLayout->addWidget(titleLabel);
    topLeftLayout->addWidget(bottomLabel);
    topLeftLayout->addStretch();

    bottomLeftLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    bottomLeftLayout->addWidget(aboutQtButton);
    bottomLeftLayout->addWidget(quitButton);
    bottomLeftLayout->addStretch();

    leftLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    leftLayout->addLayout(topLeftLayout);
    leftLayout->addLayout(bottomLeftLayout);

    rightLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

    mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addLayout(leftLayout);
    mainLayout->addLayout(rightLayout);

    setLayout(mainLayout);
    setWindowTitle("Math Helper");
    //setFixedSize(windowWidth, windowHeigth);
}
```